# If $X\sim Y$, does $\mathbb P(X\leq a,Z\leq b)=\mathbb P(Y\leq a, Z\leq b)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be 3 r.v. on the same probability space. My question is maybe stupid, but does $$\mathbb P(X\leq a,Z\leq b)=\mathbb P(Y\leq a,Z\leq b),\tag{1}$$
whenever $X\sim Y$ ? I would say no because it could happen that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent but $Z$ and $Y$ are independent. Therefore, if $(1)$ hold, we would have $\mathbb P(X\leq a,Z\leq b)=\mathbb P(X\leq a)\mathbb P(Y\leq b)$, what would contradict $X$ and $Z$ not independent. But I'm not so sure if this is really possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, here's a handy counter-example.
Let's $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$ where $X \perp Y$. Now let $Z = -Y$ meaning that $Z \sim N(0,1)$. This is exactly according to your intuition: the case where $Z$ depends on $Y$ but not $X$.

Let's evaluate the equality for $a=b=0$.

By independence:
\begin{equation}P\{X < 0, Z < 0\} = 0.25\end{equation}

However, recall that $Z = -Y$:

\begin{equation}P\{Y < 0, Z < 0\} = 0.\end{equation}

So, by counter example, (1) does not hold. Here demonstrated in the case of $X \perp Y$ and $Z \perp X$, but $Z$ dependent on $Y$.